# the read-write ext4 file system driver for UEFI

Tags: filesystems, read-write, uefi, ext4

Is there a read-write ext4 file system driver for UEFI. Currently, UEFI contains a FAT file system driver, and some read-only ext4 file system driver are available in Open Source community. But I need a read-write ext4 file system driver on UEFI, so I can write some system files on a ext4 disk before OS running. Is there any this kind of driver.

Thanks

Feng Libo

Answer (score 0):

You can try the drivers from [refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html), they also have a list of other uefi filesystem drivers on their [site](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html#finding).

Comment: Yes, I have tried these drivers, they are all read-only.